# Add a SASS mixin with Angular Renderer2

Tags: angular, sass, angular-renderer2

I would like to add the [make-col](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mixins) mixin defined by Bootstrap with the Angulars [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2).

**Context**

The idea is to create a directive that receives two inputs:

- The number of columns the element should use
- The total amount of columns

And adds the mixin to the element.

**Code**

In an ideal world it would look something like this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appCustomColumn]'
})
export class CustomColumnDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    public amountOfColumns: number;

    @Input()
    public totalAmountOfColumns: number;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
                private renderer: Renderer2) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        // This API does not exist
        this.renderer.setMixin(this.elementRef.nativeElement, '@include make-col(' + this.amountOfColumns  + ',' + this.totalAmountOfColumns + ')');
    }
}
```

**Question**
Does anyone know if you can apply a mixin through the renderer2 in Angular or if there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SASS code is compiled when you build your app and not while your app is running. You can't provide SASS code dynamically at runtime, only CSS.

Check the [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/104385c508a4c77761b04a9842e978bab6f359f6/scss/mixins/_grid.scss#L40) to see what CSS the mixin adds. Then add the CSS.

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "[appCustomColumn]"
})
export class CustomColumnDirective {
  @Input() amountOfColumns: number;
  @Input() totalAmountOfColumns: number;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(
      this.el.nativeElement,
      "flex",
      "1 1 " + this.percentage(this.amountOfColumns / this.totalAmountOfColumns)
    );
    this.renderer.setStyle(
      this.el.nativeElement,
      "max-width",
      this.percentage(this.amountOfColumns / this.totalAmountOfColumns)
    );
  }

  private percentage(n: number): string {
    return Math.floor(n * 100) + "%";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution that I went with!